# Forum on Google sites

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, phpbb, google-cloud-sql, google-sites

I want to know if we can add a forum on Google SItes ?

A Framework or a gadjet , I search on Internet but I don't Find it.

And it's possible to connect a Google Sites on a Data Base SQL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet for a forum-like experience would be the Google Groups gadget.

[image]

[Here is an explanation of what it is](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview) if you haven't used Google Groups before. Just be sure that you create the group before inserting the gadget because you need the group URL to set it up.

Comment: Thanks I know for Google Group but I don't use that.  I find an example for phpBB but I search other Application like phpBB